# How to catch exception by putting GoogleMap component inside ErrorBoundary

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps

I am trying to catch google map load error when offline, by putting `GoogleMap` component ([here](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#googlemap)) provided by `react-google-maps` inside the `ErrorBoundary` component. ([here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html))

I am not able to display the `div` inside the `ErrorBoundary` incase of an error. It doesn't even trigger `getDerivedStateFromError` or `componentDidCatch` methods.

Any idea or suggestions how to catch the exceptions like `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED` or anything similar which doesn't load the map because of an error.